How to ensure all emails are delivered using SendGrid (inc yahoo, hotmail, aol)?
We use SendGrid to send our email and were trying to sign a few users up to our product and noticed that the sign-up emails were not being delivered to hotmail, aol and yahoo emails. It works fine for icloud and gmail.
The error we get for yahoo and aol is that: Email was deferred due to the following reason(s): [IPs were throttled by recipient server]. Then for hotmail it is: Unfortunately, messages from [IP] weren't sent. Please contact your Internet service provider since part of their network is on our block list.
We got in contact with SendGrid support and they sent some recommendations but I'm not sure they'll fix the issues since I've seen quite a few people online complain about SendGrid. So I wondered if people with experience think this is fixable with the free version of SendGrid or if it's worth switching. If it's worth switching, what free or affordable options are there? We are a small start-up.

We faced a similar issue a month ago, even while using the Pro plan of SendGrid, which provides a dedicated IP for email delivery. Despite this, Gmail still blocked some of our emails due to reputation issues. To address this, we are currently focusing on improving our delivery practices, such as adhering to email authentication protocols (e.g., SPF, DKIM, DMARC), cleaning our email list, and sending to engaged users only.
I recommend prioritizing increasing your delivery rate and sender reputation, as this will help resolve many deliverability issues. However, it's worth noting that we are still blocked by Gmail in some cases, which emphasizes how important it is to maintain consistent sending habits and build a good reputation over time.
If you have enabled click tracking in SendGrid, consider setting up a custom domain for URL redirection to maintain your brand identity and avoid potential reputation issues. If click tracking isn’t enabled, you can skip this step.
If your email volume is below 100 emails per day, there’s no urgent need to switch to a paid plan or another service provider unless the free plan limitations are affecting your business. Switching to a paid plan or another provider might make sense if you need higher sending limits, a dedicated IP, or better support. However, improving your sender reputation is a critical step that applies regardless of the email service you use.
